# Jquery: how to create an element dynamically, using constructor

Tags: jquery, constructor, keyboard-events

I'm trying to dynamically create the line:

```
<td><input name="Text1" type="text" onkeyup="filterDP(this)" /> <br/></td>,
```

So I try this:

```
var td = somelement.closest("td");
td.prepend('<br/>');
td.prepend($('<input/>', {id: 'DPFilter', keyup: filterDP }));
```

Yet the event doesn't fire. The culprit should be the line keyup: filterDP, but I don't know how to fix it.
Thank you

Comment: Can you post your `filterDP` javascript method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the event inline, just bind it to the element when you create it using jQuery event methods

```
td.prepend($('<input/>', {id: 'DPFilter'}).keyup{filterDP)) ;
```

If you wanted to make your approach work it would need to look like:

```
td.prepend($('<input/>', {id: 'DPFilter', onkeyup: 'filterDP(this)' }));
```

**[Inline demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3hh8E/)**